# How to converting postcode to lat/long using Google Maps API with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am using PHP to convert a list of postcodes + County into latitude and longitude. I have tried using the google map api and the `simplexml_load_file()` function like so:

```
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=WS9+8NS,+West+Midlands&sensor=false";
$result = simplexml_load_file($url);
print"<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Now this works fine as I am able to get the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => OK
    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [type] => postal_code
            [formatted_address] => Walsall, Walsall, West Midlands WS9 8NS, UK
            [address_component] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => WS9 8NS
                            [short_name] => WS9 8NS
                            [type] => postal_code
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => Walsall
                            [short_name] => Walsall
                            [type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => locality
                                    [1] => political
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => Walsall
                            [short_name] => Walsall
                            [type] => postal_town
                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => West Midlands
                            [short_name] => West Mids
                            [type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                    [1] => political
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [long_name] => United Kingdom
                            [short_name] => GB
                            [type] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => country
                                    [1] => political
                                )

                        )

                )

            [geometry] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [lat] => 52.6030230
                            [lng] => -1.9175368
                        )

                    [location_type] => APPROXIMATE
                    [viewport] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 52.6013713
                                    [lng] => -1.9188871
                                )

                            [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 52.6040692
                                    [lng] => -1.9161892
                                )

                        )

                    [bounds] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [southwest] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 52.6020654
                                    [lng] => -1.9182516
                                )

                            [northeast] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 52.6033751
                                    [lng] => -1.9168247
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Problem now is, how should I take out the first latitude / longitude and not the whole thing, I only need these two values.

Please note that the lat/long are dynamic as the address changes for each search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `print_r` you can see the structure of the content. Then, it is a matter of following it.

This contains the values:

```
$result->result->geometry->location
```

So to print them separately, you can say:

```
print "lat: " . $result->result->geometry->location->lat;
print "lng: " . $result->result->geometry->location->lng;
```

All together:

```
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=WS9+8NS,+West+Midlands&sensor=false";
$result = simplexml_load_file($url);
print "lat: " . $result->result->geometry->location->lat . " <br/>";
print "lng: " . $result->result->geometry->location->lng . " <br/>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use their JSON API.

```
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=WS9+8NS,+West+Midlands&sensor=false";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
print"<pre>";
$resultArray = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($result);
```

Then just access like an array!

e.g.

```
$resultArray['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']
$resultArray['results']['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

I would use cURL instead of file get contents as it gives more control. But this works fine.

I would also check the $resultArray before attempting to do anything with it.

Comment: Printing the result you wrote, displays nothing.

Comment: Please note, this is how the json format looks:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=WS9+8NS,+West+Midlands&sensor=false%22

Comment: Yes, that is the JSON. Possibly you will have to use cURL to make your request instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: great answer I need to echo $resultArray['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] to return some data.